# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. vb.net on datagridview to csv export

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

Good Day,

I am running this code below to save a DatagridView1 to csv format but rowcontents.Add(c.Value.ToString()) is raising Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error ... No Idea what to do ...

```
Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(path)
        Dim rowcontents As New List(Of String)
        For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            rowcontents.Add(col.HeaderText)
        Next
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", rowcontents))
        For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            rowcontents.Clear()
            For Each c As DataGridViewCell In r.Cells
                rowcontents.Add(c.Value.ToString())
            Next
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", rowcontents))
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: The key here is that you need to verify that the contents actually exist before attempting to retrieve them. Test both c and c.Value as "IsNot Nothing" before attempting to retrieve the value.

Comment: Thanks ChicagoMike... its working like a charm ... :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)